# getting error on updating assignee and comment field in JIRA using python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira, atlassian-python-api

I am using python to automate JIRA process, while doing I am unable to update **Assignee** and **Comment** fields.

While updating Assignee field, not getting any error, but the value is not updated properly, I am trying to assign from one user to other user, but it is getting updated as **Unassigned**

For comment field, getting an error.

Below is my code:

```
from atlassian import Jira
jira_instance = Jira(
    url = "https://****.atlassian.net/",
    username = "****@gmail.com",
    password = "*******",
)

data = jira_instance.jql("project = PROJECTNAME AND status = 'IN PROGRESS' ORDER BY created ASC", fields=['description','assignee','reporter','comment'])

for i in range(len(data["issues"])):
    test_data = data["issues"][i]
    jira_instance.issue_update(test_data['key'], fields={'assignee':{'emailAddress': '####@gmail.com' }})
    jira_instance.issue_update(test_data['key'], fields={'comment':{'comments': [{'body':'This is the comment'}]}})
```

Also tried using `displayName` instead of using `emailAddress`, but still same thing happens.

For comment field, got the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/path/jiratest.py", line 13, in <module>
    jira_instance.issue_update(test_data['key'], fields={'comment':{'comments': [{'body':'This is the comment'}]}})
  File "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\atlassian\jira.py", line 891, in issue_update
    return self.put(url, data={"fields": fields})
  File "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 341, in put
    absolute=absolute,
  File "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 236, in request
    self.raise_for_status(response)
  File "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\atlassian\jira.py", line 3705, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(error_msg, response=response)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError
```

**Please anyone help me out on this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said if you're using Jira Cloud or Server.

For Jira Cloud, you must set the assignee for an issue using that person's account ID, not their username or email address, so the request would look something like:

```
jira_instance.issue.update(assignee={'accountId': '5b10ac8d82e05b22cc7d4ef5'})
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding a comment field, try something like this:

```
jira_instance.issue_add_comment(test_data['key'], 'This is the comment')
```

For updating the assignee, try this:

```
jira_instance.update_issue_field(test_data['key'], fields={"assignee": "####"})
```

Comment: adding a comment field worked as you suggested, but updating the assignee still not working. Its becomes **Unassigned**, not the other user. Please help me on updating assignee field. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm also getting same error while trying to use issue_update or update_issue_field API.
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Internal server error